# sql returning data in specified order

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `data` with an integral primary key, and a table `list`
each element of which contains an intarray of these keys.  I want a function

```
 create function getDataFromList(key integer) returns set of data
```

which returns

```
select * from data,list where idx(list[i] , data.key) > 0
```

(i.e. the rows of data whose keys are contained in the `ith` list) but I want the data returned in the order in which the keys occured in `list[i].`

I can do this with a loop but I somehow it seems one ought to be able to use a single sql statement but I can't see how.  Can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. Is `list` a table, each _row_ of which has an intarray of keys? If so, what column on `list` holds the array?

Comment: Please also paste your table definitions